# WatiN + Mozrepl-Jssh + Firefox: Can't run script

Tags: c#, firefox-addon, watin

I'm running the latest WatiN version and installed mozrepl-jsshv2.6.xpi on Firefox v31, so far pretty much everything works except for RunScript, I tried browser.RunScript and browser.NativeDocument.RunScript, both throw the exception "RunScript Failed".

I gave up on IE cause of the sluggishness and random gtliches.

Does anyone knows how to make it work?

EDIT: I found a fix, I need to add "window." before any script in order to make it work.

Comment: why don't you use the latest code which uses MozRepl and try it? I think you already have the answer using window. :) .

Comment: Hey there, unfortunately there are some websites that I would like to automate that require IE, so I'm stuck with Microsoft's solution. Thanks.

Comment: hey paul, I have been working on IE 11 only with WatiN and building common framework for our web apps. So good to see that there are people like me. If you using pure Microsoft Platform please check [Coypu](https://github.com/featurist/coypu) and [O2Platform](https://o2platform.wordpress.com/category/ie-automation/)

Comment: Hi rahoolm, I'm definitely going to check it out, I endup using the .NET browser control in order to run multiple automation instances and achieve stable results.

Comment: Can you provide more info on .NET browser with multiple instances? I would like to give it a try myself. Share your work if possible. Thanks!

Comment: Coypu seems nice however I can't get it to work, it just freezes the app when I instantiate the browser, no exceptions are thrown.